# How can I know whether the keyboard is shown or not in a Composable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I need to know if the keyboard is being shown and act accordingly, is there any way to know this in Jetpack Compose?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jetpack compose : Scroll UI upwards in case keyboard opens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68903975/jetpack-compose-scroll-ui-upwards-in-case-keyboard-opens)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Maybe I'm doing something wrong but `LocalWindowInsets.current.ime.isVisible` It's returning me false all the time, even when the keyboard is shown on the screen...

Comment: have you checked qute from accompanist documentation? You need to add `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` to make it work